# I need to change a dataframe into another datafram with groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this Pandas DataFrame:

```
        permno  date        ret         mkt_cap
0       10145   2004-06-30  0.0869436   3.14724e+07
1       10145   2004-07-30  0.026754    3.23144e+07
2       10145   2004-08-31  -0.0383542  3.09274e+07
3       10145   2004-09-30  -0.00333516 3.08243e+07
4       10145   2004-10-29  -0.060792   2.89504e+07
... ... ... ... ...
131995  61399   2019-08-30  0.106509    8.70672e+07
131996  61399   2019-09-30  -0.0199643  8.4867e+07
131997  61399   2019-10-31  0.0200073   8.61405e+07
131998  61399   2019-11-29  0.0510707   9.00941e+07
131999  61399   2019-12-31  0.0208849   9.1793e+07
```

I want to reorganize "ret" with "permno" as columns and "date" as rows

```
            10145       ...   61399

2004-06-30  0.0869436   ...   -0.007267235
2004-07-30  0.0226754   ...   0.00123355
...         ...         ...   ...
2019-12-31  ...         ...   0.0208849
```

I know I have to start from this code

```
 dataframe[['permno', 'date', 'ret']].groupby('permno')
```

but I really don't know how to complete this code to obtain "permno" as column and "date" as index.
Please, can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) your dataframe into `permno` columns and `ret` values:

```py
dataframe.pivot_table(index='date', columns='permno', values='ret')
```

Or:

```py
dataframe.pivot(index='date', columns='permno', values='ret')
```

---

As [@Nk03](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15438033/nk03) mentioned, you can leave out `values` if you want to include `mkt_cap` as well:

```py
dataframe.pivot_table(index='date', columns='permno')
```

Comment: I guess he wants both 'ret' and 'mkt_cap'. Anyways, he can remove 'values arg' if he wants to.

Comment: Thanks, I just need 'ret'. I get the following error: DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: @Andrea try `pivot()` instead of `pivot_table()` like: `df.pivot(index='date', columns='permno', values='ret')`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by writing the following code:

```
dataframe.pivot(index='date', columns='permno', values='ret')
```